# Exponents and fractions pre-calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would I go on about solving this:

## ${x^4y^7\over x^5y^5}$

When $x = {1\over3}$ and y = ${2\over 9}$

My working out:

Firstly I simplify.-

## ${xy^2\over x}$

Then substitute

## ${{{1\over3} * {2\over9}}^2\over{1\over3}}$

Further,

## ${{{1\over3} * {4\over81}}\over{1\over3}}$

and

## ${{4\over243} \over{1\over3}}$

since $a/b / c/d = ab * dc$:-

## ${4\over243} * {3\over1}$

equals

## ${12\over243}$

Simplified:

## ${4\over81}$

The correct answer is

## ${4\over27}$

Can someone help me employ the proper method in solving this problem?

Regards,

Comment: The initial simplification should be to $\frac{y^2}{x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is 
$$\frac{y^2}{x}$$
So the answer is
$$
\frac{4/81}{1/3}= \frac{4 \cdot 3}{81} = \frac{4}{27}$$

You just had the extra $x$. Must be an oversight

Comment: Argh..9 hours of re-learning maths causes this to happen. Thanks! Thought I was going insane.